# rename files in dir on button click

Tags: php, jquery, directory, rename

I have an input field containing a file name and when submit is clicked it changes the files name.

If there is more than 1 file in the directory and I change the second files input it changes the first files name.

No matter how many files are in the directory it only changes the first files name.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 rename ($file_path.$file, $file_path.$_POST['new_name']);
 header("Location: /php rename/");
 exit();
 echo "name changed";
}
else {
  echo "name was not changed";
}
```

I have looked online and cannot find a script that does what I need it to do.

i want to be able to change the second files name when i click submit on the second file form and then third/fourth and so on.

```
    <?php
    if ($handle = opendir('./uploaded/')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            echo'
    <a id="file-link" href="./uploaded/'.$file.'" target="_blank">'.$file.'</a>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="new_name" value="'.$file.'">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>    
    ';

    $file_path = "./uploaded/";

                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                    rename ($file_path.$file, $file_path.$_POST['new_name']);
                    header("Location: /php rename/");
                    exit();
                    echo "name changed";
                }
                else {
                        echo "name was not changed";
                    }


                }

            }
    closedir($handle);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: where do `$file_path` and `$file` come from, the latter obviously contains the filename of the first file in the directory, if that's the only one being changed

Comment: You're going to need a loop to make sure you perform the action on all the files that fit your criteria.

Comment: ($file = readdir($handle) and $file_path is just a variable with the file path.

Comment: @DevlshOne how would i do that?

Comment: sort of. i used readdir to list all files in a folder. then i put a rename button and input field (with value="$file") so you can edit name and rename button submits the form. it works but whichever input field i type in it always changes the first files name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to rename all files in the directory on click of a button. $handle is already a handle to the directory and $file_path contains the path of the directory. Also assuming that the name of all input fields for new filename field is new_name[]. You need to iterate though each file in the directory and rename it like below:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $i = 0;
 while($file = readdir($handle)) {
  rename ($file_path.$file, $file_path.$_POST['new_name'][$i]);
  $i++;
 }
 header("Location: /php rename/");
 exit();
 echo "name changed";
}
else {
 echo "name was not changed";
}
```

Ajax Solution with Javascript

test.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function changename(id,dirpath){
    new_name = document.getElementById(id + "_new_name").value;
    old_name = document.getElementById(id + "_old_name").value;

    old_file_path= dirpath + old_name;
    new_file_path = dirpath + new_name;
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById(id + "_old_name").value=new_name;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","change_name.php?old_name="+old_file_path+"&new_name="+new_file_path,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
  $dirpath="testdir/";
  $handle = opendir($dirpath);
  print '<div id="response"></div>';
  print "<table>";
  $i=0;
  while($file = readdir($handle)) {
   if($file!="." && $file!="..") {
    $parameters = $i . ",'"  . $dirpath . "'";
print "<tr><td><input type='text' id='{$i}_new_name' value='{$file}' /></td><input type='hidden' id='{$i}_old_name' value='{$file}' /></td><td><input type='button' name='change' value='Change Name' onclick=\"changename({$parameters});\" /></td></tr>";
$i++;
   }
  }
  print "</table>";
 ?>
 </body>
</html>



change_name.php

<?php
 if(isset($_GET['old_name']) && isset($_GET['new_name'])) {
$old_name = $_GET['old_name'];
$new_name = $_GET['new_name'];

if(file_exists($old_name)) {
    rename($old_name,$new_name);
    echo "file renamed from ($old_name) to ($new_name)";
}
else {
    echo "file does not exist";
}
}

?>
```

Ajax Solution with Jquery

test.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".change_class").click(function() {
        dirpath = "testdir/";

        id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        new_name = $("#"+id+"_new_name").val();
        old_name = $("#"+id+"_old_name").val();
        console.log(new_name + " " + old_name);

        old_file_path= dirpath + old_name;
        new_file_path = dirpath + new_name;

        $.ajax(
                {
                 url:"change_name.php?old_name="+old_file_path+"&new_name="+new_file_path,  
                 success:function(data) {
                            $("#response").text(data);
                            $("#"+id+"_old_name").val(new_name);
                        }
                }
            );

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$dirpath="testdir/";
$handle = opendir($dirpath);
print '<div id="response"></div>';
print "<table>";
$i=0;
while($file = readdir($handle)) {
if($file!="." && $file!="..") {
    print "<tr><td><input type='text' id='{$i}_new_name' value='{$file}' /></td><input type='hidden' id='{$i}_old_name' value='{$file}' /></td><td><input type='button' name='change' class='change_class' value='Change Name' id='{$i}' /></td></tr>";
    $i++;
}
}
print "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

change_name.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['old_name']) && isset($_GET['new_name'])) {
    $old_name = $_GET['old_name'];
    $new_name = $_GET['new_name'];

    if(file_exists($old_name)) {
        rename($old_name,$new_name);
        echo "file renamed from ($old_name) to ($new_name)";
    }
    else {
        echo "file does not exist";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: i want to rename individual files. every file has an input box next to it with a submit button. this is wrapped in a form.

Comment: If you want to rename only the file whose button was clicked, this this the approach you will need to take.

Comment: one approach: Instead of placing all the file names and new file names in single form,you will create one form for each file when rendering it in html.While rendering it,you can put a $num(incremental counter) value in the button fields value.When one of the buttons is clicked, only form form is submitted and from the value of the submitted form's button(get the $num value),you can know for which file renaming has to take place.Check if($i==$num) is true inside the while loop, then only rename the file.This assumes no new files are added or deleted to that folder between rendering and renaming

Comment: is it possible to do it with ajax?

Comment: @sam I have added code to do it with ajax in my previous answer only. I have done it using javascript only, you can use jquery instead

Comment: how would i do it with jquery?

Comment: @sam I have added code to do it with jquery also in that previous answer only.

Comment: the jquery code doesnt seem to change the name and i have tried putting a link next to each file to open image in new tab. but i cant seem to get the link to change on along with the name. how would i do this?

Comment: @sam The query code is working fine. I have tested it and then sent it to you. Did you change the folder path at two places in the code. $dirpath='testdir/" at one place in PHP and dirpath="testdir/" at one place in jquery